# Remove title bar of JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, titlebar, jinternalframe

Does anyone know how to remove the title bar of a [`JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)?

I already know to set `frame.setBorder(null);` to remove the borders, but the title bar remains. I hope you can help.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. i searched before i asked but i must have overlooked this post.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upvote yet. I only have 12 rep points, I'm new to this site.

Comment: @Developer You don't need to remind people how the site works. People will up-vote your answer if they want to.

Comment: @Duncan: no its our duty to teach our new peer. if he don't know the rules?

Comment: it's okay, i have already upvoted Developer's answer. i just got to 15 rep.

Comment: -1 and voted to close: sorry, but without further details of what you _really_ want to achieve this question isn't answerable (though it attracts answers in all shades of wrongness ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as that..

```
jInternalFrame1.setUI(null);
```

Try.. Thanks..

Comment: ... removing the delegate is *wrong always*, it will silently have odd effects (nothing of the internalFrame-ness will survive), be re-installed equally silently the next time the LAF is toggled (or internals feel like calling updataUI)

Comment: @kleopatra If you know a better approach, or perhaps that it's not possible, do you have time to add an answer to [the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218608/hiding-title-bar-of-jinternalframe-java) so that this knowledge is not lost.

Comment: @Duncan the basic technical answer is to remove/replace the northPane (and not forget to do it again after minimizing and some other caveats) - so without knowing _why_ the OP wants to not show it the question simply is not answerable. Anyway, whatever the requirement, this answer is plain wrong (as is the similar answer to the duplicate ;-)